# How to install spoonacular python package

Tags: python, spoonacular

I'm trying to use the spoonacular python API found here https://github.com/ddsky/spoonacular-api-clients/tree/master/python

However, I can't seem to figure out how to install it in a virtualenv.  I'm used to installing packages using pip.  So when the instructions say to install like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID.git
```

do I need to save this directory (https://github.com/ddsky/spoonacular-api-clients/tree/master/python) to my own GitHub repo?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is a´happening if you try it with pip ? Any erros ?

Comment: First you have to activate your virtual environment . Which OS are you using. ?

Comment: Hi @SebNik , there is a PyPi spoonacular package `pip install spoonacular` But this is not the official repo.  It pulls from https://github.com/johnwmillr/SpoonacularAPI . I want to install the official repo as it appears there are new api calls in the official repo.

Comment: Hi @dejdej , I'm using MacOS and I've activated a virtualenv.  In my case, I use `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: okay then try `pip install git+https://github.com/ddsky/spoonacular-api-clients.git`

Comment: Hi @SebNik , when I try that I get:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/4r/9rt6hh115cxg8hbn52xp3sr80000gn/T/pip-req-build-03ekl9jz/setup.py'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4r/9rt6hh115cxg8hbn52xp3sr80000gn/T/pip-req-build-03ekl9jz/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right something is strange, I tried a more direct approach:

1. First activate your virtual environment
2. Clone repo : `git clone https://github.com/ddsky/spoonacular-api-clients.git`
3. Install the package manually:

`$ cd spoonacular-api-clients/python`

`$ python setup.py install`

It should work:
[image]