# How to access spoonacular API with Python?

Tags: python, api, installation, git-clone, spoonacular

I tried to download the Software Development Kit for python on the Web Site but I don't know to access the folders content. The documentation isn't very helpful.

I tried to clone the github repository like this: [How to install spoonacular python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575187/how-to-install-spoonacular-python-package)

But when I try to install the package manually:

```
$ cd spoonacular-api-clients/python

$ python setup.py install
```

I get this:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-5784.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Comment: Did you try using ```--user``` ?

Comment: I try now pip install and it worked! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python setup.py install --user
```

Will work. It will install the module for the current user. To install for all users run:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```